# I am Trying to input data using form Placeholder name

Tags: javascript

I am Trying to input data to a form using Form Placeholder Name. FormFilling Not Starting Even Form Filling Function is called.

```js
if (Data[key].formname) {
  //console.log(key)
  //console.log(Data[key].value)

  $("[placeholder='" + Data[key].formname + "']")[1].value = Data[key].value;

  //console.log(key)
  //console.log(" Done")

  await wait(2000);
}
```

Error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined`

Comment: You don't provide enough code to answer. Your `$("[placeholder='"+Data[key].formname+"']")[1]` is `undefined`

Comment: i Update the code now check it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My comment remains valid. We don't know what's your HTML, we don't know what's in `Data[key].formname`. So whatever it is, there is no element with attribute `placeholder` that matches `Data[key].formname` Actually, let me rephrase, there are no *TWO* elements that matches that selector.